# Filter in datagridview Column with multiple words

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview wher there is an searchbox to search a specific colomn.
I tried to connect the filter to a column with 2 words: "Shipment to" but whene I run the code it fails and throws an "SyntaxErrorException"
When I set the filter on an 1 named column: "date" I have no problem.

Is it imposible to filter on an column that has multiple words?

the filter:

```
            BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
        source.DataSource = this.sourceGrid.DataSource;
        sourceGrid.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        source.Filter = String.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", tableColumn, this.Text);
```

Comment: AFAIK neither a database nor a DGV column name can be more than one word. Recheck the real column name!

Comment: Datagrid and the datagridview handles words with multiple words, I'm looking at one now :P
the colomn name is realy "Shipment to"

Answer (score 0):

A found my problem, with a little help from Taw
I must set the colomns of the datagrid to a single name and change only the Headertext:
Datagridview.Colomns["Shipmentto"].HeaderText = "Shipment to"

that did the trick :)